# Convert Varchar column to datetime

Tags: sql

I have two columns as below. ColumnA is a varchar. 9bd is an assigned number, 10 is fiscal year, 07 is month, and the rest is unique id. ColumnB is datetime.

```
ColumnA            ColumnB  
9db1007000001      8/7/2011
```

I would like to seperate from ColumnA into a Month column (datetime) and a Year column (datetime).

Desired result from ColumnA:

```
Column Month     Column Year 
7                 2010
```

OR

```
7                 10
```

I can seperate ColumnB into Month column and Year column. Here is my attempted SQL script.

```
SELECT
ColumnA,
DATEPART(mm, (ColumnB))    as Month,
DATEPART(yy, (ColumnB))    as YEAR
FROM MY TABLE
```

Can someone please help? I did search within this website and found similar question but my attempted script produces error

```
--Conversion failed when converting datetime from character string.

SELECT
CAST(SUBSTRING(ColumnB, 5, 2) + SUBSTRING(ColumnB, 3, 2) AS DATETIME) Month_Year 
FROM MY TABLE
```

BTW, this  `DATEPART(yy, (ColumnB))` function returns 2011. How can it return 11 instead? 
Or should I submit another question?

Comment: `ColumnB` is a VARCHAR, and so are the values you're extracting using `SuBSTRING`. How do you expect the `CAST` of the two characters from `ColumnB` to be cast to a DATETIME? The value you're extracting is an  string (`10`) that at best you can convert to an integer. It's not a DATETIME, and you can't cast it to one any more than you can `ABCD` into currency. CAST doesn't perform magic. As to your second question, what's wrong with merely subtracting 2000 from the value: `DATEPART(yy, (ColumnB)) - 2000`

Comment: @Ken - thanks for your feedback. Regarding to second question, Yes I can do that for one record. How about substracting million of records?

Comment: It's exactly the same. I don't understand the question. `SELECT  DATEPART(yy, MYOldColumn) - 2000 AS TheYear FROM MyTable` works just fine for every row in the table, regardless of whether there's one or a billion. (You can also obviously add a `WHERE` condition to that `SELECT` to only retrieve certain rows.)

Answer (score 0):

the conversion from a string to datetime requires the string in a proper format, which depends on your DB settings too.

for the second question about getting the last two digits, I suggest to use modulo instead of subtraction - you never know whether it's 2000 or 1900, unless you are 100% it's 2000

a quick example:

```
SELECT  SUBSTRING(columnA, 4, 2) AS FiscalMonth,
        SUBSTRING(columnA, 6, 2) AS FiscalYear,
        CAST(SUBSTRING(columnA, 6, 2) + '-01-'  + SUBSTRING(columnA, 4, 2)  AS DATETIME) Fiscal, -- in format of YY-dd-MM, but this really depends on your settings
        DATEPART(MM, ColumnB) AS [Month],
        DATEPART(YY, ColumnB) % 100 AS [Year]
FROM    yourTable;
```